# Solr as a Geocoder

Tags: solr, lucene, geocode, google-geocoder

I am using SOLR for my search server. I wondered if it is possible to or advisable to use it for geocoding. I was going to use it for postcodes, cities and towns. I hope to have a structure like this:

Name: London
Long/Lat: 1.1/-1.2
Country: UK

Name: Manchester
Long/Lat: 1.1/-1.2
Country: UK

Name: SN5 3PW
Long/Lat: 1.1/-1.2
Country: UK

Would something like this work? I could then have unlimited requests without having to use a map or having a branded searchbox like I do with google and others.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-spatial/) which explains a similar design.

Google `geospatial Lucene` for more.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Spatial4J or Lucene-Spatial playground](http://code.google.com/p/lucene-spatial-playground/) which is committed to lucene spatial (version 4) as well which is pretty decent. Google for RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy and GeohashPrefixTree by David Smiley.

Comment: Hi. Do these actually allow geocoding though? It seems like it is just an improved spacial search module for dealing with long/lat

Comment: I reckon they do, You can add geo tagged shapes to the index.